# TortoiseSvn showing an error "unable to connect to repository at url"

Tags: svn, tortoise-svn

I want download the complete code of

`https://code.google.com/p/stm32modbus/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2F%20stm32modbus%20--username%20ickingdom%40gmail.com`

using TortoiseSVN, but after doing svn checkout it shows an error that it is unable to connect to the repository at the url.

How can I download the code?

Answer (score 1):

Click on the Checkout tab in the page - https://code.google.com/p/stm32modbus/source/browse/

I see you are using an incorrect URL to checkout the code. This is the URL needed to check out the code. Give this in the Tortoise SVN check out location bar.

```
http://stm32modbus.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/
```

Comment: Thank you sir @deppfx, you have detected the exact error , now it is done successfully.

Comment: @Mangesh Choose it as an answer if it resolves your problem. It helps others as well.